# Downgrade Windows 7 from 64-bit to 32-bit?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, 32-bit

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Can I legally downgrade from Win 7 64 bits to Win 7 32 bits?](https://superuser.com/questions/261879/can-i-legally-downgrade-from-win-7-64-bits-to-win-7-32-bits)
>   [Windows 7 and Vista Activation FAQ: how do language, version, 64-bit or 32-bit, and source affect ability to install and transfer Windows licenses?](https://superuser.com/questions/303136/windows-7-and-vista-activation-faq-how-do-language-version-64-bit-or-32-bit-a)

Is it possible to downgrade Windows 7 64-bit to 32-bit?

A friend of mine bought a laptop with 64-bit Windows 7 on it and he wants to have 32-bit (some software is malfunctioning). Is it possible to downgrade Windows 7 64-bit to 32-bit? If not, is it possible to somehow re-install it (restore to factory settings or what not), but to choose 32-bit? The laptop is a Toshiba (I can find out the exact model if that makes any difference).

Comment: Downgrade from 64 to 32-bit requires a complete reinstall.  As a side note for OEM copies (i.e. purchased with a computer rather than full Retail copies) your downgrade rights are limited and you need to contact your supplier, Toshiba in this case, to find out if your machine is licenced for 32-bit and if they can supply you the media.

Comment: @Mokubai: Note that we have [Windows 7 and Vista Activation FAQ: how do language, version, 64-bit or 32-bit, and source affect ability to install and transfer Windows licenses?](http://superuser.com/questions/303136/windows-7-and-vista-activation-faq-how-do-language-version-64-bit-or-32-bit-a).

Comment: @TomWijsman Oh wow, that's neat.